# Is there an option to turn on "warnings as errors" programmatically in C++ in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I would like to turn on the "warnings as errors" feature for just me, but not other programmers who share the same code. I can use a macro like `#ifdef MY_VERSION` to limit this.

However, I can't see a way to turn on this feature (the `/WX` compiler switch) inside of the code.

Or alternatively, to set a range of warnings as errors, e.g. something like `#pragma warning (error: 4000-4999)` which would let me set this for just me but noone else.

Or possibly some other way to ensure that when code with `MY_VERSION` defined is built, warnings are treated as errors, but when it isn't defined, they aren't.

I've tried to find something in the MS docs, but haven't managed to do so. There may be something involving the "Project Engine", but if so I don't understand how to go about it.

Comment: Um, what's wrong with [`#pragma warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170)? It has an `error` option to let you "Report the **specified warnings** as errors". I wouldn't try disabling a range of warnings for an entire file, but specific warning on an as-needed basis.

Comment: Why do you want the switch inside the code? Putting the switch inside your code intrinsically shares it with others sharing the code, so you have to resort to something like your `MY_VERSION` macro to shield others from the switch. Putting the switch inside your Visual Studio configuration keeps the switch out of the others' hands. It's like you want to make things needlessly hard for yourself.

Comment: The problem with pragma warning is that there are hundreds of warnings, so using it to imitate the /WX option isn't really on. However, I may well be making this harder unnecessarily due to not knowing enough about VS. How do I put the switch in my personal VS configuration, rather than inside the vcxproj file (which is shared via version control) ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same effect by simply setting it in your project.
(properties)(c++)(general) set treat warnings as errors to Y.  Your cohorts leave it at 'N'.

Note that I am assuming that each developer has their own project setup.